# Windows Forms - using public event to subscribe Form to a user control event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I have an issue when it comes working with events and/or delegates. I saw very similar questions but still the real implementation is not clear to me. So please when you answer be more specific so I can try and eventually understand how exactly creating/handling of public/custom events work by doing it in a code I know.

What I have is a `User Control` which is simply a text box and a button I need to change a record in a database using the value from the text box. I'm using this control for many forms so I need to know which entity exactly I'm using and be able to call it's own save method. Doing all that will be easier if I just can use the `click` event of the button from my `User Control` and then call the `Save()` method of the current form.

This is my User Control :

```
namespace UserControls.CommonControls
{
    public delegate void ClickMe(string message);

    public partial class ChangeCode : UserControl
    {
        public event ClickMe CustomControlClickMe;
        public ChangeCode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CustomControlClickMe != null)
                CustomControlClickMe("Hello");
           //ToDo fill
            //MessageBox.Show("To Do: Write the busieness logic.");
        }

        public void SetTextBoxMask(MaskedTextBox txtBox)
        {
            txtChange.Mask = txtBox.Mask;
        }
    }
}
```

I post it with the last attempt I made to try and implement what I need.

This is one of the form that need to use the `Click` event from the `User Control` and more specific the `Constructor` because if I understand right there is the place where I have to subscribe for the event :

```
public MaterialEdit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserControls.CommonControls.ChangeCode. += new ClickMe(button2_Click);
        }
```

`UserControls.CommonControls.ChangeCode` - this is how I reach my `User Control` it's named `ChangeCode`.

Comment: Are you missing some code in `MaterialEdit` constructor, or is this exact paste? How did you add `ChangeCode` control to the form?

Comment: No this is the exact code. I'm doing it in the Visual Studio 2010 designer. Just drag and drop to the forms where I use the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you pasted it is not clear that you added `ChangeCode` control to your form. To use the control and it's events and properties, first you must create new instance to it and add it to the form. This is done:

- In designer, by dragging control from Toolbox to the form
- In code editor, by invoking control constructor and adding new object to control collection

Only then can you handle event of that object. Let's say that you dropped `ChangeCode` control to a form, and that Visual Studio named it `ChangeCode1`. You attach a handled to `CustomControlClickMe` event like this:

```
ChangeCode1.CustomControlClickMe += new ClickMe(button2_Click);
```

Code you pasted (`UserControls.CommonControls.ChangeCode. += new ClickMe(button2_Click);`) is incorrect for several reasons:

1. Syntactically, left hand side expression ends with `.` which makes it incorrect assignment target (`UserControls.CommonControls.ChangeCode.`)
2. Event name is not provided, only the control name (you need to end left hand side of assignment with what you want to assign to - `.CustomControlClickMe`)
3. You are trying to attach handler to a class and not an object

Comment: I'm gonna try and rewrite my code according to what you've wrote. Just to make it clear `UserControls.CommonControls.ChangeCode.` - I know it's not correct I wanted to see if I'll get tip for the event name. It's was just to see if at some moment I'll get access to it.

Comment: And this is from my designer: `this.ucChangeCode = new ShoesUnlimitedAdmin.UserControls.CommonControls.ChangeCode();` So the correct syntax (from what I understand) should be `ucChangeCode.CustomControlClickMe += new ClickMe(button2_Click);` is that right?

Comment: Yes. That would be the object you want to attach handler to, as opposed to a class.

Comment: Lol, It works now. I just had to use the name from the designer :) Thanks.